# spark sql casting binary to string in parquet doesnt work

Tags: apache-spark-sql

This one work as expected

```
%spark.sql
select cast(binary('AA==') as string);

result
CAST(AA== AS STRING)
AA==
```

But when I read binary data from a parquet file and then cast it it doesn't work as expected.

```
select cast(value as string), value from sometable;
CAST(totalminustax.value AS STRING) value
�  [B@3aad2758
    [B@3859414a
    [B@6b2b58c5
```

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I had to use `.config("spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString", true)` to solve this problem.